# In ggplot2 how to put only some values on to an axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let's say I have a database named cars that has sales by car brand in them. I want to make a chart and put all of them on the X-axis except "Nissan". Can I do that without filtering it out from the data?

I would like it to be something like this:

`ggplot (cars, x=brand -"Nissan", y=sales)`

Thank you

Comment: You'd need to remove the observations from data.frame in the data argument, not only the x argument i.e.  `ggplot(data = cars[cars$brand != "Nissan", ], aes([...]`. Also your ggplot call is not correct (missing aes)

Comment: Do you not want "Nissan" to be plotted or you just want to omit it from the labels? Check out `scale_x_manual`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you can do it "without filtering". You need to filter at some point. You can filter with base R `cars[cars$brand != "nissan", ]` or with dplyr `filter(cars, brand != "nissan")`

Here is example with real data:

```r
library(tidyverse)

mpg %>% 
  filter(manufacturer != "nissan") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = cty, y = hwy, color = manufacturer)) + 
  geom_point()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-10-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>